# Accessing NPGSQL in Startup.cs using DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Using .NET Core 2.1, NPGSQL, Entity Framework and Linux.

From Startups.cs' Configure function, I am calling a function in a dependency injected class that in turn calls another dependency injected class which accesses the DB using Entity Framework + NPGSQL.

**Configure Services:**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
        .AddDbContext<MMContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql($"Host='localhost'; Port=1234;Database='mydb';Username='test';Password='test'"))
        .BuildServiceProvider();
        services.AddTransient<IMusicManager, MusicManager>();
        services.AddTransient<IMusicRepo, MusicRepo>();

      services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

**Configure function:**

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMvc();

        using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var mm = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMusicManager>();
            mm.DoSomeDBStartupStuff();
        }
    }
```

**IMusicManager**

Implementation looks like this:

```
    private readonly IMusicRepo _musicStoreRepo;
    public MusicManager(IMusicRepo musicStoreRep)
    {
        _musicStoreRepo = musicStoreRepo;
    }

    public void DoSomeDBStartupStuff()
    {
        _musicStoreRepo.InsertSampleStuff();
        _musicStoreRepo.CheckThisAndCheckThat();
    }
```

**IMusicRepo**

Implementation looks like this:

```
    private readonly MMContext _context;
    public MusicRepo(MMContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void InsertSampleStuff()
    {
        _context.Music.AddAsync(new music("abc"));
        _context.Music.AddAsync(new music("123"));
        _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

**MMContext**

This is implemented as so:

```
public class MMContext : DbContext
{
    public MMContext(DbContextOptions<MMContext> options) : base(options) {}
    ... OnModelCreating etc...
}
```

I get this exception on firing it up:

> Application startup exception: System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Reset() called on connector with state Executing at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Reset() at
>   Npgsql.ConnectorPool.Release(NpgsqlConnector connector) at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Close(Boolean wasBroken) at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Dispose(Boolean disposing) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose() at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Dispose()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.Dispose()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Dispose() at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.Dispose()
>   at MM.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment
>   env) in \Startup.cs:line 122
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder
>   app) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   app) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   builder) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

I am not sure what is causing the issue. Possibly the way I am using Dependency Injection and the way I am using the scope? Help appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share the issue/exception details? 
And where and how is your DbContext configured?

Comment: It doesn't seem like your registering Entity Framework anywhere in your code... Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db?tabs=visual-studio#register-the-context-with-dependency-injection

Comment: sorry! I will add vital information as soon as I can

Comment: @Rollhard Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight exactly what you need, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I've added additional info - apologies, but I was trying keep things simple and exclude too much noise.

Comment: Noted. You however have to take care that by removing too much it makes the question more confusing than clear.

Comment: Show entire Configure Services.

Comment: Also why are you calling `.BuildServiceProvider();` That is unclear from the short snippet of code provided

Comment: Also noticing async calls not being awaited in a void function. This could cause threading issues.

Comment: Make `DoSomeDBStartupStuff` async and properly await any async calls. Consider moving those startup stuff to a hosted service that will execute on startup

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  What do you mean a hosted service? This is .NET Core Web Application.

Comment: @Rollhard check doc here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noticing async calls not being awaited in a `void` function.

```
public void InsertSampleStuff()
{
    _context.Music.AddAsync(new music("abc"));
    _context.Music.AddAsync(new music("123"));
    _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

This could cause threading issues with the `DbContext` when you try to save those changes.

Either make the function async and await those calls properly or use the synchronous API

```
public void InsertSampleStuff() {
    _context.Music.Add(new music("abc"));
    _context.Music.Add(new music("123"));
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If going the asynchronous route then consider moving that setup code into a hosted service and properly awaiting it there

Reference Reference [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Thank you! Background task with hosted service is resolving the issue :-)